# Difference between ItemsSource and DataContext as pertains to ListBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datacontext, itemssource

I am not quite grokking the difference between ItemsSource and DataContext.  Can someone explain it and back it up with examples?  When would I use one or the other.

I am reading the docs and it says that I can bind using DataContext, but I throw an ObservableCollection at it and nothing shows up in the list.  If I throw the same collection at the ItemsSource, it works fine.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Controls (including the ListBox) don't do anything with the value of `DataContext` at all.  Its purpose is to provide a context for data **bindings**.

Lets assume you have a `ListBox` "myList" and a `MyData` "myData".  The `MyData` type has a property "People" of type `ObservableCollection<Person>` and in turn the `Person` type has the string properties "Forename" and "Surname".

All of the following are equivalent:-

```
 myList.ItemsSource = myData.People;
```

or

```
 myList.DataContext = myData;
 myList.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("People"));
```

or

```
 myList.DataContext = myData.People;
 myList.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

Typically though bindings are configured in Xaml and the DataContext of the LayoutRoot is assigned the data object:-

```
 LayoutRoot.DataContext = myData;
```

you might have the following Xaml:-

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <ListBox x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Forename}" Margin="2" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" Margin="2" />
         </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

You'll note a couple of things here.  The `DataContext` of "myList" is not assigned at all.  In this case the control's ancestor tree is walked until an ancestor is found that does have a value assigned to the `DataContext` property.

Also each `ListBoxItem` dynamically generated for each `Person` instance has that `Person` instance assigned as its `DataContext` which is how the Forename and Surname bindings manage to work.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is the first understandable explanation I have found.