# Cannot bind objects to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

Cannot bind objects to `ListBox`. Data are there I guess it is something about `Binding`.

Any clue?

**C#**

```
   public sealed class Package
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public List<PackageItem> PackageItems { set; get; }
    }

    public sealed class PackageItem
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public PackageItemTypes PackageItemType { get; set; }
    }

private ObservableCollection<Package> availablePackages;

 lbPackageList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        lbPackageList.DataContext = availablePackages;
                    }));
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="lbPackageList"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Package.FileName}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Error**

> System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides
>   DataContext. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type
>   'Object')

Comment: @ConradClark System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: See post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169245/difference-between-itemssource-and-datacontext-as-pertains-to-listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
 lbPackageList.ItemsSource = availablePackages;

 void engine_PackgesChanged(Models.Package newPackage)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("There is a new package here " + newPackage.FileName);

            try
            {
                lbPackageList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                   {
                       if (availablePackages.Contains(newPackage) == false)
                       {
                           availablePackages.Add(newPackage);
                       }
                   }));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // 
            }
        }
```