# ListBox not working with DataContext

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox

I am trying to display data using `ListBox`. I am setting the `DataContext`.

```
public class DataStore
{
    static ObservableCollection<ItemToTrack> _items =
        new ObservableCollection<ItemToTrack>();
    public static ObservableCollection<ItemToTrack> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

The xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the method where the DataContext is set:

```
private void FillBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataStore.Items.Add(new ItemToTrack() { Name = "Gold palate", Locations =
        new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            { "DB City", 101 }, { "Agrawal Jwellers", 110 }
        }});
    DataStore.Items.Add(new ItemToTrack() { Name = "Crockery set", Locations =
        new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            { "DB City", 200 }, { "New market", 210 }
        }});
    ItemList.DataContext = DataStore.Items.ToList();
}
```

No error is generated except that nothing appears in the `ListBox`.
If I change DataContext to ItemsSource in c# code, data is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListBox` in your XAML or code behind, not the `DataContext` - which would just be used for binding to any properties on the ListBox, not any of it's children.

Comment: But DataContext is meant for Parent so that its children can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value of `ItemsSource`, the control will generate the templated items internally.
Setting `DataContext on an ItemsControl` will NOT achieve this.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169245/difference-between-itemssource-and-datacontext-as-pertains-to-listbox) to see the good explanation about `DataContext` and `ItemsSource`.