# DataTemplate on ListBox.ItemsTemplate is acting weird

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

When I bind my `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection<Items>` it dynamically, at the press of a `Button`, appends itself `ListBoxItem` children which have the result of `Items.toString()` in its content property. Although I don't understand why its children have `Items.toString()` as its content property, that's not my problem (I think it's related, though).

My problem is, when I add a Template to it, it doesn't show anything. I'll divide my code in two scenarios.

## **Scenario 1:**

### *C Sharp*

```
myListBox.DataContext(myObservableCollection);
myListBox.setBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

### *XAML*

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Height="200" Width="425" Margin="312,94,113,256">
```

#### The `ListBox` shows:

-The returned result from item1.toString();
-The returned result from item2.toString();
...

## **Scenario 2:**

### *C Sharp*

```
myListBox.DataContext(myObservableCollection);
myListBox.setBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

### *XAML*

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Height="200" Width="425" Margin="312,94,113,256">                        
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--property1 to property4 are properties of the type Items-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding property1}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding property2}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding property3}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding property4}"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

#### The `ListBox` shows:

nothing at all!!!

Thanks in advance, the resources I've already checked that have somewhat helped me but not completely are: [DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169245/difference-between-itemssource-and-datacontext-as-pertains-to-listbox), [DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801822/datatemplate-for-listbox-element-is-not-binding-at-all) and many MSDN articles.

Comment: are you sure all the `property1`, `property2`, ... are ***actually*** properties (with a getter and a setter)? Anyway the issue is related to binding here, so try viewing the ***Output*** window to see if there is any error notified there.

Comment: You, sir, saved my life and made my day. Thank you very much. I feel really dumb, though.